# Permissions Required for ASP.NET processes to Delete files on a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a web application "MyAPP" hosted on IIS 7.5. It is running as ApplicationPoolIdentity with username "MyAPP".
I have granted full control to these users on a directory

- IIS_IUSRS
- IUSR
- ASPNET\MyAPP

When I tried to delete any of the files in that directory from the application, I get an error Access Denied.
I tried giving all the permissions, but could not resolve this isssue. Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Check that the users have access to the directories above as well. At least read access.